# Capture Screen Shot Using Javascript Not Working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to take a screenshot Of my web application page on Button click. For this I am using html2canvas in My Javascript Code But It Is Not Working In IE. But It Is Working In Chorome. This Is The Code I am Using For Capture My Screen Shot.

**`Main Function--`**

**

```
function screenshotPage() {
       var element =  document.getElementsByTagName("body");
         html2canvas(element, {
         useCORS: true,
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                $(childWindow.document).ready(function () {
                    $(childWindow.document).contents().find('#previewImage').html(canvas);
                });
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         }); 
    }
```

**

**`Calling Function--`**

```
function generate() {
         screenshotPage(); 

    }
```

How Can I Work for It In IE . Please Help Me.

Comment: HTML1300: Navigation occurred. .. Showing This in Console

Comment: no errors .. but screen shot capture not working.

Comment: I don't Know HTMLCollection.